# Check null result before accessing property or calling method

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I would like to know if there is a better way or general rule to check null result before accessing property or calling method in C# Linq or lambda expressions. Thanks in advance.

At my understanding, to avoid exception like "Object reference not set to an instance of an object" or "Check null from Lambda result before accessing CSharp property or calling method", I should use "if" statement, or "try/catch" block like:

```
 var product1 = _myProductRepository.FindOne(p => p.Id == -20301); 

//1. use "if" statement to let code flow continue

if(product1 != null) // to prevent exception "Object reference not set to an instance of an object."
{
      int id1 = sh1.Id; // note: accessing property "Id" is safe here
      Console.WriteLine("Product Id: {0}", id1);

}


//2. use "try/catch" block to let code flow continue

var product2 = _myProductRepository.FindOne(123);

var possibleItems  = product2.Orders.Where(x => x.Id == -1);

List<Order> myOrderList = null;

try
{
       myOrderList = possibleItems.ToList(); // note: ToList() method call is safe here
}
catch
{
       myOrderList = new List<Order>();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't Where clause return a empty list if nothing is present? What do you need a try catch there?

Answer (score 2):

> I should use "if" statement, or "try/catch" block like:

In general, I would prefer an explicit `null` check if the `null` return is something that is expected as part of the normal operation of your application.

In your case, this is likely true, as finding a product seems like an operation that very well could fail, as a product may not exist.

That being said, if the ID is a known element and really should always be in the DB, then `null` would not be an expected result.  In this case, the `FindOne` method really shouldn't return a `null` instance, and that is truly an exceptional case, then exception handling may be preferred.

Comment: Agreed.  Exception handling should be completely separate from regularly functioning business logic.